# How can add black background behind the UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

Hello I want to show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` on my `UIViewController` exactly like this

[image]

How can I draw a UIViewIndicator like this above image

I have tried this

```
func showIndicatorView(){

        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        loadingIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 05

        loadingIndicator.opaque = false
        loadingIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.6)
        loadingIndicator.center = self.view.center;
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        loadingIndicator.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it in another view that has a black background color. Something like this. You could also add the 'Loading...' label in that view if you need it.

```
func showIndicatorView(){

    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    let backgroundView = UIView()

    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 05
    backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
    backgroundView.opaque = false
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.6)

    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    loadingIndicator.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    let loadingLabel = UILabel()
    loadingLabel.text = "Loading..."
    let textSize: CGSize = loadingLabel.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: loadingLabel.font ])

    loadingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height)
    loadingLabel.center.y = loadingIndicator.center.y

    backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width + 70, 50)
    backgroundView.center = self.view.center;

    self.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
    backgroundView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    backgroundView.addSubview(loadingLabel)
}
```

Comment: Yes I need the loading.. also ... could you please add that as well in your code

Comment: Well I could put that too, but...Do you use XIBs or storyboard? Its way easier and cleaner to do this there and not from code.

Comment: I am using storyboard

Comment: You could created a custom view there. But if you don't want to I updated my answer with the label. I didn't get to test it though.

Comment: It is displaying label with the loader but there are some layout issues. could you try your code at your end so you'll know

Answer (score 1):

Use MBProgressHud library .

This is what you need :-

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD